# Partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve following PDE using `DSolve` but there is no result upon completion-

```
DSolve[D[-A[r,t],t]D[A[r,t],r]+A[r,t]D[D[A[r,t],r],t]==0,A[r, t], {r, t}]
```

Comment: `DSolve[]'s` support for `PDE's` is still somewhat limited,
 so don't be surprised if some things don't work yet :P. Try alternative -> `Maple`.

Comment: The approach `A[r,t]=R[r]T[t]`(separation of variables) solves the pde without any restriction concerning `R[r],T[t]` ???

Answer (score 1):

Your `pde` leads to $1=1$. So any two random functions $R(r)$ and $T(t)$ give a solution.

Solve 
$$
-u_{t}u_{r}+u\ u_{rt}=0
$$

Let $u=R\left(  r\right)  T\left(  t\right)  $ then the above becomes

\begin{align*}
-\left(  RT^{\prime}\right)  \left(  R^{\prime}T\right)  +\left(  RT\right)
\ \left(  R^{\prime}T^{\prime}\right)    & =0\\
R^{\prime}T^{\prime}  & =R^{\prime}T^{\prime}\\
1  & =1
\end{align*}

So try any random functions, $R(r)$ and $T(t)$, they will be a solution

```
ClearAll[r,t,solvePDE]
solvePDE[R0_,T0_,r_,t_]:=Module[{u},
   u=R0 T0;     
   Simplify[D[-u,t]D[u,r]+u D[D[u,r],t]]
]

 solvePDE[Sin[r],Exp[-t],r,t]
 (* 0 *)

 solvePDE[Sin[r]*Cos[r]+2*r,Exp[-t]+t+Tan[t],r,t]
 (* 0 *)

 solvePDE[r^3, t^8, r, t]
 (* 0 *)
```

May be Mathematica should just have returned  $F1(r) F2(t)$ as an answer?